# How to debug into dynamically-loaded jars in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, jar, intellij-idea, imagej

I'm writing a plugin for ImageJ, with an Ant script to put all the needed files into a jar. ImageJ loads all the jars in a directory, and I run my plugin. However, when I try to debug my program, IntelliJ claims that there was "No Executable code found at line x in class y". How might I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double check that source code you build corresponds to the classes packaged in the jar, they must be synchronized. If you have a jar loaded that is built from the older sources it may cause such problem. Also ensure that you compile with debug info enabled. If compilation is performed from Ant, you must specify **debug=true** attribute for the **javac** Ant task.

If there is some obfuscation or bytecode manipulation involved in the Ant build, it may also cause issues when debugging.

Comment: Thanks - it was the `debug=true` I was missing.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way of specifying whether to set that debug flag based on whether I've clicked "run" or "debug"? Or will I need two separate configurations?

Comment: No, these things are not related. This flag only affects compilation that is performed from Ant.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you'll need the source code to see what you're debugging.  Every time you add a JAR you also have the opportunity to tell IntelliJ where to find the source files that accompany it.  See if you can do such a thing for your case.

Comment: I'm not adding the jar file to IntelliJ per se, I just have it being created using an Ant script. Should I be doing something differently? IntelliJ certainly knows where all my source is (that is, the Modules tab of the Project Structure window has my source directory in its "Source Folders" list). Java newbie here, so you may assume I've done something naive :-P